# How should I proceed with establishing a Remote Infrastructure management system for my [small] company?

Tags: networking, remote, infrastructure

My company is having a small IT infrastructure. Details are:

1. 125 computers
2. One mail server
3. One NAS
4. and One database server

We want to establish a remote infrastructure management system, where in our team located in another city can manage the infrastructure and provide support. How should I proceed?? Should we go for Open Source systems like ZenOSS or OPENSIMS or NAGIOS??? What type of resources do such deployment requires??

OR Should I outsource RIM??? How much will it cost (per/system)??
   Our current dept. provides

1. Help desk support
2. Asset management
3. Backup and other maintenance activities
4. Network Monitoring

I am into management, so I am not aware of the trends. So any suggestions/help will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposals:

First of all, they will need remote access through the networ, like through a VPN. They will need admin accounts or so to do the job

Help Desk support: They can remote desktop to computer (assistance mode), or use software like DameWare

Asset Management: Can be done for free with [GLPI](http://www.glpi-project.org) and OCS NG

Backup: they could stick with your current solution. An autoloader would be helpful, so they don't have to ask someone to switch backup tape everyday

Network monitoring: a big universe. Open Source (Nagios with centreon / cacti/smokeping...), commercial (Solarwinds, what's up gold, Microsoft SCOM...)

You choice must be based on your needs and the skills of your teams to rollup and manage these solutions. Open source means more skills, commercials means direct money

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems like our current IT team can implement it. What are the approx per/node charges, If I outsource these services.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which operating systems you're using, but if you have a Windows -based network, I suggest a combination of Active Directory + Group Policy + VPN + VNC. Maybe throw a network monitor like Nagios in for good measure.

Comment: It is a Windows based network. My IT team is suggesting OpenSIMS. I guess that includes Nagios.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably cost more if you want to use your own monitoring software, and then outsource support.  [HP's criticalwatch](http://h20219.www2.hp.com/services/us/en/continuity-availability/missioncritical-criticalwatch.html) or [Inteq's infraops](http://www.inteqnet.com/infrastructure-monitoring.html) will do the monitoring using their blend of software.  Cost per system will depend on what exactly you want them to do, it probably wouldn't be a per node cost since you aren't looking for per node monitoring (help desk, maintenance network mon. etc).